# wordpress plugin or anyway to make dynamic posting images and text in 3 columns

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am a beginner in wordpress, i want something dynamic to display a 3 column post in my section like this in my screenshot
[image]

is there any way or something a plugin to make my site easier to display like this ? or please if there is a guide to output with this by coding dynamically i am very willing to learn. I have a little knowledge about WP_Query post but not very crucial to built something like this. Please help or something guide me to output like this. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq for a 3 column layout using html/css.

Comment: what do you mean with "dynamic" ? for example, load the last tree post? or some other content type ?. there is a lot of "block builders" for making that task really easy, most of the themes creators have their own builders. 
i know a few but are payed options: https://www.elegantthemes.com
[Visual Composer] (https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-extension-block-builder-addons/12279745?s_rank=28)

Comment: thank you for your answer sir dynamic , i mean the admin dashboard will able to make it upload image and post it simply in the homepage

Comment: Have you head about Advanced Custom Fields? - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: not yet sir ... :'(

Comment: can i make dynamic posting images with divided into 3 columns with advance custom fields plugin ?